# Qt c++ QSystemTrayIcon not on tray, windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, qt

what am i doing wrong? Program runs and compiles but icon is not on tray.
My OS is Windows 7.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget * parent )
    : QMainWindow( parent )
     , ui( new Ui::MainWindow )
{
    QMenu * trayIconMenu;
    trayIconMenu = new QMenu();
    QSystemTrayIcon tray;
    QIcon icon( ":/ok.png" );
    tray.setIcon( icon );
    tray.setContextMenu( trayIconMenu );
    tray.show();
    ui->setupUi( this );

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `QSystemTrayIcon` destroys as soon as the execution exists your `MainWindow` constructor. You should rather do this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget * parent )
    : QMainWindow( parent ),
      ui( new Ui::MainWindow )
{
    QMenu * trayIconMenu = new QMenu();
    QSystemTrayIcon *tray = new QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon( ":/ok.png" ), this);
    tray->setContextMenu( trayIconMenu );
    tray->show();
    ui->setupUi( this );    
}
```

Comment: @tomite, I guess the tray icon exists, however something wrong with the icon (image). Please check whether the icon with ok.png image is created.

Comment: it is 32x32 black bmp image and i put it in .../Qt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QCreator/bin/myproject/ i tried 16x16 also

Comment: @tomite, do the following: `QIcon icon(":/ok.png"); Q_ASSERT(!icon.isNull());` to check whether the icon is not empty.

Comment: ok, the icon is empty but why? png image is in myproject folder and i thought my image is the problem but then i downloaded http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/images/used-in-examples/widgets/icons/images/monkey_off_16x16.png    
icon from example and it's still not working

Comment: @tomite, you create the icon as if you use the resource system (qrc file). Try to use the full path to the image file like `QIcon icon(".../Qt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QCreator/bin/myproject/ok.png");`